# Constraining values using wildcards with the MarkLogic Optic API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

Using the MarkLogic 10 Optic API, Is it possible to do wildcarded constraining with `op:where()`?

In the below table I'm trying to return all rows that start with a `"HELLO"` value, **ONLY** in the `Table.Message` column.

```
Test.Table.Message
HELLO123
HELLO1234
HELLO12345
HELLO1123123123123
BYE1234
    
version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic" at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
        
op:from-view("Test", "Table")
  =>op:where(op:eq(op:view-col('Table', 'Message'), 'HELLO*'))
  =>op:result()
```

Adding an asterisk or % as a trailer to the `op:where(op:eq(op:view-col('Table', 'Column'), 'HELLO*'))` clause does not return results.

In the optic API guide, there is also an example of a `cts:word-query()` being used within an `op:eq`, but this does not work as well: `op:where(op:eq(op:view-col('Table', 'Column'), cts:word-query('HELLO')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with [`op:sql-condition()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/op:sql-condition) using the SQL `LIKE` operator

```
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic" at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";

(:op:from-view("Test", "Table"):)
op:from-literals((
  map:entry("Message", "HELLO123"),
  map:entry("Message", "HELLO1234"),
  map:entry("Message", "HELLO12345"),
  map:entry("Message", "HELLO1123123123123"),
  map:entry("Message", "BYE1234")
), "Table")
=> op:where(op:sql-condition("Message LIKE 'HELLO%'"))
=> op:result()
```